PyQt5 - Return the value of a textbox that's next to a checkbox created via looping
I'm created a PyQt5 dialog that builds a form based on a supplied pandas DataFrame. Each row of the form contains a QCheckBox with a name, a type label, and a status QLineEdit. The user is able to select/deselect rows and change the contents of the status QLineEdit. When the user clicks the OK button, I want the onokclick function to find the rows that are checked, get the value of the QLineEdit for that row, and upload that value to a database. Here is the code I have now:
class EditDetails(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, dftable, srecnum, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Select Names and Edit Status")
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.dftable = dftable
        self.srecnum = srecnum
        
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.glayout = QGridLayout()
        self.glayout.addWidget(QLabel("Name"),0,0)
        self.glayout.addWidget(QLabel("Type"),0,1)
        self.glayout.addWidget(QLabel("Status"),0,2)
        
        i = 1
        for index, row in self.dftable.iterrows():
            checkbox = QCheckBox(row["Name"])
            checkbox.setChecked(True)
            self.glayout.addWidget(checkbox,i,0)
            slabel = row["Type"]
            qtlabel = QLabel(slabel)
            self.glayout.addWidget(qtlabel,i,1)
            qtentry = QLineEdit(row[srecnum]["status"])
            self.glayout.addWidget(qtentry,i,2)
            i += 1
        vlayout.addLayout(self.glayout)
        
        newqw = QWidget()
        newqw.setLayout(vlayout)
        scrollarea = QScrollArea(widgetResizable=False)
        scrollarea.setWidget(newqw)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(scrollarea)
        
        QBtn = QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.onokclick)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox,i,0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    
    def onokclick(self):
        widgets = (self.glayout.itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(self.glayout.count()))
        for widget in widgets:
            if isinstance(widget, QCheckBox):
                if widget.isChecked():
                    name = widget.text()
                    status = ??? # How do I fetch the contents of the QLineEdit widget that's in the same grid layout row as this QCheckBox?
                    self.uploadToDatabase(name, status)


Why are you throwing away i when iterating over the widgets? The indexes of the checkboxes are given by for i in range(3, self.glayout.count(), 3), which means the index of each line-edit will be simply i + 2.

Alternatively, create a list containing a tuple of widgets of each row. Just do something like self.rows = [], then do self.rows.append((checkbox, qtentry)) for each iteration of the initial for loop, finally, just iterate through for row, (checkbox, qtentry) in enumerate(self.rows): in onokclick(), and eventually update the database based on the checkbox.isChecked(), using the row index and the qtentry.text(). There's really no "Qt magic" here, and iterating through all widgets in a layout is completely pointless (especially since it's a grid): it's just simple program logic.

Thanks to @musicamante I was able to get this working.
    ...
    self.widgetrows = [] # Create empty list for rows
    i = 1
    for index, row in self.dftable.iterrows():
        checkbox = QCheckBox(row["Name"])
        checkbox.setChecked(True)
        self.glayout.addWidget(checkbox,i,0)
        slabel = row["Type"]
        qtlabel = QLabel(slabel)
        self.glayout.addWidget(qtlabel,i,1)
        qtentry = QLineEdit(row[srecnum]["status"])
        self.glayout.addWidget(qtentry,i,2)
        self.widgetrows.append((checkbox, qtentry)) # Add row to list
        i += 1
    vlayout.addLayout(self.glayout)
    ...
def onokclick(self):
    for widgetrow in self.widgetrows:
        if widgetrow[0].isChecked():
            name = widgetrow[0].text()
            status = widgetrow[1].text()

